# how to search a text in solr using REST Api?

Tags: solr

I have a query in Elastic Search shown below

[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR7Xq.jpg)

How can I perform the same using Solr?

Answer (score 0):

You can search by query string like given below.

```
http://domain/solr/core_name/select?q=*:*&fq=studentId:14466&wt=json&indent=true
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nikunj I tried it by using GET, but unable to get using POST

Comment: Hey @Nikunj please do refer the following link for POST Method  https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/3.1/REST_API_Reference/Solr-API.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single match against a field in standard Lucene syntax:

```
q=field:value
```

Having field names with characters outside of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` isn't recommended, but you could probably escape it properly with `student\ I\'d:14466`.